# Find gap between two successive non-zero data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame a with some 0 and non-zero values. For example:

> 0,2,6,1,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,3,3,0,0,2,0,0,7,1,4,0,7,0,5,6,0,0,0

I need to find the length between the **successive non-zero occurrences**. I have tried to implement which(a!=0) using it inside a loop but cannot make it work to work for ***successive*** criteria. The output should look like:

> 4,3,6,4

*Note that the non-zero data will not count if it is not successive to another non-zero data.*

**Edit:::**

Sorry for the confusing output in the question. I did +1 in every output because my data-frame is time between two successive rainy days. The output can also be:

```
3,2,5,3
```

But the main thing is "if there is just one non zero value between two zeros, it will not count" as "non-zero values that are not adjacent to other non-zero values should be treated as zeros." (Like 16th item 2).

Comment: It looks like the expected gap for first is 3

Comment: rle to the rescue, I also think the first case equals 3

Comment: I don't understand the output - `2, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5` - three 0s between the `2` and the `5`, your output says 4 - looks like the "length between" is "number of 0s plus 1". Then `...5, 4, 0, 0, 3`, 2 0s, your output is 3, makes sense. Then `...3, 3, 0, 0, 2`, 2 0s, your output is 6???

Comment: To answer Gregor's Question. There should least be two-non zero values in successive order. So 6 is is gap between ......3,3,0,0,2,0,0,7,1. The two in the middle does not count because it is alone.

Comment: Ok, I still don't get how do you even count 5 consequent numbers on this input?

Comment: It counts 0,0,2,0,0 as five values between 3 and 7 in the series .....3,3,0,0,2,0,0,7,1......

Comment: I would rephrase *"if there is just one non zero value between two zeros, it will not count*" as *"non-zero values that are not adjacent to other non-zero values should be treated as zeros."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = c(0,2,6,1,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,3,3,0,0,2,0,0,7,1,4,0,7,0,5,6,0,0,0)

xt = x
# replace lone non-0s with 0
xt[which(lag(x) == 0 & lead(x) == 0)] = 0

# use RLE, ignoring the first element
with(rle(xt == 0), lengths[c(-1, -length(lengths))][values[c(-1, -length(lengths))]]) + 1
# [1] 4 3 6 4
```

Comment: @Henrik thanks for the pointer - now trimmed both sides.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough

```
vector_c <- c(0,2,6,1,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,3,3,0,0,2,0,0,7,1,4,0,7,0,5,6,0,0,0)

x <- rle(vector_c == 0)

x$values
x$lengths

x$lengths[x$values]
```

Comment: This seems like it is calculating gaps between 0s, not gaps between non-0s. Drop the `!` to match OPs title (even if OP's output is still confusing).

Comment: Oh ok makes sense to me

Comment: Maybe I should also drop the first and  last cases as those are not really a gaps...

Comment: Sorry for the confusing gap. My main problem is I need to avoid non-successive non-zero values like 16th item in the data-frame 2. I need to find the gap between **successive non-zero** values. So if there is just one non zero value between two zeros, it will not count.